# php does not serve an image to html?

Tags: php, html, image

I am trying to serve an image to html via php script. But I am stuck and its not working :-(
Below is my image.php script

```
<?
    $_GET['f'] = 'all_three.jpg';
$image = null;
$image = file_get_contents($_GET['f']);
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    echo $image;
?>
```

and below is my index.html

```
    <html>
    <head>
       <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
       <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
       <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <img src="image.php" alt="Image" />
    </body>
   </html>
```

The link to image is "hard-coded" inside the php, all I am doing is calling "image.php" to serve that hardcoded image and it does not work! What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Do you have the correct path names? Does the image actually exist?

Comment: have you tried to access image.php directly to see if it is working as expected or displaying some error?

Comment: index.html,image.php, all_three.jpg are inside my htdocs/testwebsite/

Comment: What happens when you try to open the image url directly? Also you can use your browser's debugging tool to look at the http request for the image and see what is happening.

Comment: @user2959229  I tried accessing "image.php" directly and its a blank page.

Comment: @Vatev, accessing image-url directly displays the image correctly.

Comment: @rich,  regarding what errors I am getting, i frankly don't know. I have installed firebug, firephp, etc etc and I still have no clue how to debug this php script.  I am new to php scripting.

Comment: What happens when you View > Source after loading the blank image.php?

Comment: @user2979010 Firebug won't debug your php. You would need to see your server logs for that. Make sure that your get var actually has the value you expect. Also you shouldnt need to set $image to null first.

Comment: @Quentin, when I view->source after loading image.php, i can see the php script

Comment: @rich, how do i check the server logs? I am using xampp with Apache and MySql running

Comment: @user2979010 Ignore my comment on server logs. That is me forgetting that my setup here is a bit different (errors all hidden)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when I view->source after loading image.php, i can see the php script

**Either:**

You are depending on [short tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php), but your server is configured to not support them.

Their use is not recommended, stop using them. Use `<?php` instead of `<?`

**Or:**

Your server does not support PHP. Install PHP on it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is on Content-Encoding, what's Text editor are you use ? Notepad 6.x ?
If yes please try:

```
Encoding > Encode in UTF-8 without BOM
```

BOM make php file have a more content and image doesn't accept another content else image